# save checkbox value to sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, checkbox

I have my insert method on DBHelper class working and on my MainActivity.java I have:

```
if (mydb.insertItem(userinput.getText().toString(), userdesc.getText().toString(), checked)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The third parameter on insert is a Boolean value from a checkbox, my problem is how do I get the value like I do on Strings by using sometext.getText().toString(). How does that work on Booleans?
Please help
On my adapter class I have:

```
itemViewsHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked( item.isChecked() );

        itemViewsHolder.cbdone.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                Items itm = (Items) cb.getTag();
                itm.setChecked( cb.isChecked() );

                if(cb.isChecked()){
                    String s = itm.getName();
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: how you are using checkbox add all code

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of check:

```
String.valueOf(checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can associate your check box selection status with 1 or 0, 1 for check box Checked and 0 when check box is not checked. this way you can use you 1 for true and 0 for false.

or something like this.

```
 boolean checked = false; //declare a boolean variable
if (checkbox.checked condition) // check checkbox status.
            checked = true;  // proceed accordingly.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store value of checkbox in SQLite in the form strings, because there   is
   no boolean data type in SQLite.

```
    String flag;
   if(cb.isChecked())
    {
        String flag = "true";
    }else{
        flag = "false";
     }
   System.out.println(flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

if a checkbox is checked you can get the bool value (true or false) with value = checkbox.isChecked();

if it is true, save as a 1 in your db, if not save as a 0